# Android viewflipper with multiple layouts

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have created and android application and it has  transition actions in inside a layout
here is tht layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_register"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout" >


    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_screen_index_layout"
            layout="@layout/home_screen_index"

             />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_screen_recover_layout"
            layout="@layout/home_screen_recover" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/home_screen_register_layout"
            layout="@layout/home_screen_register" />


    </ViewFlipper>
```

in thr i have include the other relevent layout using  tag. 
I have made the development clearly.

That layout has been loaded in to HomeScreen.java activity class
But now i want to call the button actions in home_screen_register_layout but it should be in a different class not in  HomeScreen.java is it possible to connect layout to a class and detect actions in that particular class.

The purpose of having this is to minimize the codes in HomeScreen.java class

Answer (score 0):

As you want to define Button click methods inside separate abstract class, I would suggest you to define a base class by extending Activity class, and then extends that BaseActivity class to your HomeScreen class. There way your HomeScreen would be able to access methods from that BaseActivity class.

For example:

### BaseActivity.java

Include all the buttons click methods here in BaseActivity class.

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

        /**
         OK button click
        **/
        public void btnOkClick(View v)
        {
        }

        /**
         Display button click
        **/
        public void btnDisplayClick(View v)
        {
        }
}
```

### HomeScreen.java

```
public class HomeScreen extends BaseActivity {
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_home_screen);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to add multiple view in ViewFlipper

```
 private View viewText;
 private View viewImage;
 private void setViewFlipperPost(String postType) {

     if (postType.toLowerCase().toString().equals("text")) {

            viewText = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.activity_full_screen_textpost, null, false);
            viewText.setTag(TAG_TEXT);
            viewFlipper.addView(viewText);

    } else  if (postType.toLowerCase().toString().equals("image")) {

            viewImage = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layoutViewImage, null, false);
            imgView.setTag(TAG_IMAGE);
            viewFlipper.addView(viewImage);
    }
}
```